# Installing GD extension in Docker

Tags: php, docker

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to install PHP **GD** extension.

This is my current Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql bcmath gd
```

When running the docker via `docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d` I'm getting a lots of errors and in the end I get this message:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (zlib) were not met:

Package 'zlib', required by 'virtual:world', not found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables ZLIB_CFLAGS
and ZLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
ERROR: Service 'php' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql bcmath gd' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Without the "gd" at the end the Docker container runs normally.

What could be the problem and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can try to add these settings in Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Official [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php). Hope it's help you.

Comment: Thanks, I ditched Alpine version of php and nginx and everything works fine now.

Comment: This seems to be working properly on my build with PHP 8.0.9-fpm

Comment: why is the package called "libpng-dev" here and "libpng" there?

Answer (score 15):

In my docker using **PHP8.0** I got **GD working for jpg,png and webp** by adding the following lines to my `php.dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

# Install dependencies for GD and install GD with support for jpeg, png webp and freetype
# Info about installing GD in PHP https://www.php.net/manual/en/image.installation.php
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libwebp-dev \
        freetype-dev

# As of PHP 7.4 we don't need to add --with-png
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-freetype
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
```

Comment: All I needed was the "libpng-dev" prior to installing gd

Answer (score 4):

One more way to approach the issue is to use `install-php-extensions` in Dockerfile:

```
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
install-php-extensions gd xdebug
```

Works in Alpine and PHP8.
Docs [here](https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer)

Comment: Helpful for me on Alpine 3.1.4. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If someone has problems installing php-gd extension in Docker, look up to [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723707/dmitry) comment or [Documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/php) and search for "PHP Core Extensions".

You can see full code on my [Github](https://github.com/grunburg/docker-nginx-php-setup), if you want to see how am I running my NGINX and PHP with php-gd extension.